# Process Builder - how to create a new record, and put a link to it on the source object?

Tags: process-builder

Upon Opportunity update, I check if the stage is of a certain value, and if a reference field "Deal Desk" is blank.   If both criteria are true, I want to create a new Deal Desk record, and put its ID into the Opportunity's "Deal Desk" field.    How can I get the ID of that newly created record?

[image]

Comment: Choose the type as text or some thing else that may let you add the formula

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could do this by building a process builder flow on the creation of Deal Desk. So this flow would, theoretically, kick off another flow looking for creation of the Deal Desk record.